# Restart Ubuntu sound processes via command line

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, audio, reboot

I tried to hibernate Ubuntu (which fails, but thats another issue) and resumed my system.

After this, the sound doesn't get played.

What command can/should I run to restart the ubuntu sound system.

Comment: see also https://askubuntu.com/a/15224/17060

Comment: Did [Dan Walker’s answer](https://superuser.com/q/17312/150988#17315) work for you?  If it did, it would be nice if you would add a comment saying so.  If not, why did you accept it? You should accept an answer [only if it works for you](https://superuser.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If Ubuntu is still using Alsa for its sound engine (I'm not sure as its been awhile since I've used it), you can restart by typing `sudo /etc/init.d/alsa-utils restart` into the terminal.

Since it doesn't seem to be working, you might need to make sure that nothing is trying to use it. (example shamelessly stolen from [the Ubuntu forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=2742327))

```
name@comp:~$ lsof | grep pcm
sh 5079 name 70u CHR 116,6 13639 /dev/snd/pcmC0D0p

name@comp:~$ kill -9 5079
```

Comment: You may also have to restart pulse-audio.

Comment: Nice try. Good answer. But in my case, doesn't solve the problem. Yes, to my best knowledge, I use ALSA itself.

Comment: Any specific order to follow. Restarted both. No luck. I am confident, by restarting my system, sound will work. But I dont want to.

Comment: Seems like I will have to kill firefox, chrome, and gnome-panel. As good as restarting the system :| . Anyway, thanks!

Comment: That's what I ended up having to do @LakshmanPrasad - I had, easily, 12-18 pulse processes. Cut that down to ~6 after closing everything except gnome.  It's easier, if not too windows-y to just restart.

Answer (score 145):

As suggested by [mikewhatever](https://askubuntu.com/users/20054/mikewhatever)
in [his answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/230888/309110#230893) to [this question on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/230888/309110):

```
pulseaudio -k && sudo alsa force-reload
```

Comment: This is the one that worked for me, on Ubuntu 18.04 ("bionic")

Comment: Works on 20.04 as well.

Comment: Works on KDE Neon 5.18.

Comment: this is the best solution, because after the notebook sleep and I used to listen music I had strange noises, now with this restart everything is Ok !!! Great ! Great !

Comment: Works on 20.10 too.

Comment: In my case, I am using 20.04, if I start an android emulator and then watching Youtube, the sound from the Youtube will have sort of electronic noise. Using this command fixed the problem.

Comment: Works on Pop OS 20.04 as well! Thank you!

Comment: Also fine on Ubuntu 22.04 !

Comment: Saved me a reboot on Ubuntu 20. Much appreciated.

Comment: This is what I have (and working) to re-scan all audio devices on Ubuntu 16.04 - `pulseaudio -k && pactl load-module module-detect`

Answer (score 37):

PulseAudio is a user service, so run systemctl with the **--user** flag.

```
systemctl --user restart pulseaudio
```

Comment: I get `Job for pulseaudio.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl --user status pulseaudio.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.` Any advice?

Comment: @json-c11 Does this restart ALSA too?

Answer (score 7):

Ubuntu swichted to pulseaudio some time ago, so it would be:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/pulseaudio restart
```

EDIT: In case that doesn't cut it, you could also rmmod and modprobe the kernel modules used for sound. Which those are probably depends on your sound card. lsmod might give you a clue...

Answer (score 5):

**Pipewire restart for Ubuntu >= 22.10**

[Pipewire](https://pipewire.org/) became [the default sound framework since Ubuntu 22.10](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2022/05/ubuntu-22-10-makes-pipewire-default), so now you need to:

```
systemctl --user restart pipewire.service
systemctl --user restart pipewire-pulse.service
```

Learned from: https://askubuntu.com/questions/230888/is-there-another-way-to-restart-the-sound-system-if-pulseaudio-alsa-dont-work/1374982#1374982

Open applications may need to be restarted to pick up the newly restarted service.

Comment: this the only one that works, at least for Pop!_OS 22.04 (equal to Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy)

Answer (score 1):

Alsa Usage:

```
 /sbin/alsa {unload|reload|force-unload|force-reload|suspend|resume}


sudo alsa reload
```

Comment: Can you expand your answer a little to explain it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I reverted to a previous kernel after a reboot. Sound was restored.  I found out that the newer upgraded kernel did not have the extra modules installed like the older one did. lsmod listed no sound modules.